# Apache AH00035 error: is it possible to place site directory on a mounted media without losing security?

Tags: permissions, apache2

I tried to put site files on an encrypted disk that's mounted to `/media` and got

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/media/username/partition') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

So I checked `/media/username` directories and they are `drwxr-x---`. I don't really remember if that was my fault or is it standard behavior. Is it possible to still have apache sites on a mounted media without giving every user permission to list it?

Comment: Possibly can do by creating virtualhosts the configuration pointing to the needed location. How is the current approach of your public directory? is it simply under `/var/www` that is pointed to?? or are you having multiple websites enabled?

Comment: Have you really read my question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can; You must enable execution for all directories and reading flag for every file to `www-data` user. Obiouvsly the `www-data` user must be the owner or in the file's group.

You can use this command:

```
chgrp -R www-data /yourdir
find /yourdir -type d -exec chmod 770 {} +
find /yourdir -type f -exec chmod 660 {} +
```

Comment: Have you really read my question?

Comment: Yes, and I think your error (specifically: search permissions are missing ) is that the apache user doesn't have the execution permission on the folder ...you can't navigate through folder without execution bit

Comment: read it again, it's not about one-time fix for the error, it's about data security

Comment: I read it again. I try to explain my thoughts: the data security are maintained by the fact that only the owner of the file and www-data group can read the file on the mounted media. You can't read something in your media without having read permission on file and execution permission on all the folder to the path. The script that I've suggested to you, it's not one time fix, it's the initial configuration of the folder, and then it's not necessary other modification. If this doesn't help you: please explain better your trouble.

Comment: Ok, looks like I was wrong, yeah. I'll review that later, thanks.

Comment: The problem is that in case of external drive `/media/username/partition` directories are re-created after remounting, aren't they?

Comment: @gafreax "only the owner of the file and www-data group can read the file on the mounted media" ... No, you're using 775 and 664. You're making the files and directories accessible for the whole world. You want 770 and 660.

Comment: @gafreax Also, instead of those two `find ... -exec chmod` commands, you could just run `chmod -R ug=rwX,o= /yourdir`. The capital X will only set the execute (search) bit for directories, so one command works for both.

Comment: @StevenKath yes the correct mode is 660 and 770, my fault.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. Note that *all* the folders must be readable and executable by www-data, including /media and /media/username, even if the files are in /media/username/someSubDir.

Comment: put double quotes around the braces `"{}"` or any folders with spaces are going to cause you issues